# Can't make machines in VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox

Okay my problem is that when I make a virtual machine in VirtualBox it came with this error here

```
Kernel driver not installed (rc=-1908)

The VirtualBox Linux kernel driver (vboxdrv) is either not loaded or there is a permission problem with /dev/vboxdrv. Please install virtualbox-dkms package and load the kernel module by executing

'modprobe vboxdrv'

as root. If it is available in your distribution, you should install the DKMS package first. This package keeps track of Linux kernel changes and recompiles the vboxdrv kernel module if necessary.

where: suplibOsInit what: 3 VERR_VM_DRIVER_NOT_INSTALLED (-1908) - The support driver is not installed. On linux, open returned ENOENT.
```

I have then tried to find a solution on Google where I had looked on this side here [How do I install virtualbox-dkms?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/203586/how-do-i-install-virtualbox-dkms) but without a solution.
That means I have tried to reinstall virtualbox-dkms.

Can you guys help me find a solution it will make me so happy.
- Jimmi

Comment: Have you done the `modprobe vboxdrv`, if nothing just reinstall virtualbox. You probably installed a new kernel and Virtualbox didn't build it's module into the new kernel yet, so that's why it can't do anything.

Comment: When I try to install modprobe vboxdrv it always fails an tell me this

"jimmi@BubbieBjoern:~$ sudo modprobe vboxdrv
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'vboxdrv': Required key not available
"

and when I reinstall VirtualBox the same error happens

Comment: Like in my first comment, just reinstall virtualbox and it will handle everything by itself.

Comment: sorry had forgot some of the text have tried reinstall 2 times now but same issue happens

Comment: Have you enabled vm support in your bios?

Comment: It should be enabled as what I can see

Comment: Look into this [UEFI Secure mode enabled?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/762254/why-do-i-get-required-key-not-available-when-install-3rd-party-kernel-modules)

Comment: Try another installation path. You have 3 choices: 1. install from Ubuntu repositories, 2. download DEB from Oracle, [3. use the Oracle repository](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41478/how-do-i-install-the-virtualbox-version-from-oracle-to-install-an-extension-pack). I always install from the Oracle repo.

Comment: What exactly helped you Jimmi?

Comment: That link you gave me here https://askubuntu.com/questions/762254/why-do-i-get-required-key-not-available-when-install-3rd-party-kernel-modules