# "Failed to start LSB: VirtualBox Linux kernel module"

Tags: virtualbox

Ubuntu-server 17.04 x64, Cinammon 3.2.7, Kernel 4.13.3 generic.

Attempting to set up VirtualBox, though so far I have been unable to start any virtual machine. Upon installation (apt install virtualbox), I get the following lines near the end of the installation process:

```
● virtualbox.service - LSB: VirtualBox Linux kernel module
Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/virtualbox; generated; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2017-09-21 19:57:07 +04; 18ms ago
Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
Process: 463 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/virtualbox start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
CPU: 28ms

Sep 21 19:57:06 Hiigaran systemd[1]: Starting LSB: VirtualBox Linux kernel module...
Sep 21 19:57:06 Hiigaran virtualbox[463]:  * Loading VirtualBox kernel modules...
Sep 21 19:57:07 Hiigaran virtualbox[463]:  * No suitable module for running kernel found
Sep 21 19:57:07 Hiigaran virtualbox[463]:    ...fail!
Sep 21 19:57:07 Hiigaran systemd[1]: virtualbox.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Sep 21 19:57:07 Hiigaran systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: VirtualBox Linux kernel module.
Sep 21 19:57:07 Hiigaran systemd[1]: virtualbox.service: Unit entered failed state.
Sep 21 19:57:07 Hiigaran systemd[1]: virtualbox.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Tried following the top answer in [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/203586/how-do-i-install-virtualbox-dkms) question, by removing virtualbox-dkms and installing it again. This resulted in the same lines as above.

Attempting to start a virtual macine, I get an error giving the following details:

```
Kernel driver not installed (rc=-1908)

The VirtualBox Linux kernel driver (vboxdrv) is either not loaded or there is a permission problem with /dev/vboxdrv. Please reinstall virtualbox-dkms package and load the kernel module by executing

'modprobe vboxdrv'

as root.

where: suplibOsInit what: 3 VERR_VM_DRIVER_NOT_INSTALLED (-1908) - The support driver is not installed. On linux, open returned ENOENT.
```

The modprobe command results in:

```
modprobe: FATAL: Module vboxdrv not found in directory /lib/modules/4.13.3-041303-generic
```

Comment: It's not just your setup, I can reproduce this on several different computers running Ubuntu Mate 18.04. I never had this problem with 16.04 or any other version of Ubuntu, so I think there might be something wrong with the bionic package. It looks like you have to go the [virtualbox.org](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads) route to make this work, be sure to install the virtualbox-6.0 package, NOT the 6.1 package. I also mentioned this in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/53200967#53200967). I would make this into an answer if the question were re-opened.

Comment: Also if a high rep user reads this and thinks my comment is helpful, and is willing to edit this comment's content directly into the answer, just go ahead, as per my profile all of my stuff is public domain, I don't care about attribution or the 2 rep points, just do it. Hiigaran (the original poster of this answer) hasn't been seen here in a while.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Solution seems to be to not install the virtualbox package that comes with Ubuntu. Following the steps to add a 3rd party repository as shown [here](https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppa/virtualbox.org_contrib), then installing the virtualbox-5.1 package appears to get things working with no further actions required.

Comment: This worked for me on Ubuntu 16.04. On 14.04 it failed, but the standard `sudo apt-get install virtualbox` worked fine.