# Installation VirtualBox on Ubuntu 18.04 fails

Tags: virtualbox, 18.04

In order to install VirtualBox (basically as it is described [here](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads)) on my Ubuntu 18.04 machine, I run the following commands

```
echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian bionic contrib" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list
wget -q https://www.virtualbox.org/download/oracle_vbox_2016.asc -O- | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update
```

All of them run fine. But for

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-5.2
```

I got the error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 virtualbox-5.2 : Depends: libqt5opengl5 (>= 5.0.2) but it is not installable
                  Depends: libqt5printsupport5 (>= 5.0.2) but it is not installable
                  Depends: libqt5x11extras5 (>= 5.6.0) but it is not installable
                  Depends: libsdl1.2debian (>= 1.2.11) but it is not installable
                  Recommends: libsdl-ttf2.0-0 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

When I use the default Ubuntu repository, the installation returns the error which is exactly described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/958110/failed-to-start-lsb-virtualbox-linux-kernel-module/958156).

After the installation, I cannot start any VM (e.g. `NAME`) and I got the error

```
WARNING: The character device /dev/vboxdrv does not exist.
     Please install the virtualbox-dkms package and the appropriate
     headers, most likely linux-headers-generic.

     You will not be able to start VMs until this problem is fixed.
Waiting for VM "NAME" to power on...
VBoxManage: error: The virtual machine 'NAME' has terminated unexpectedly during startup with exit code 1 (0x1)
```

Of course, `virtualbox-dkms` package is installed.

The model name (`cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep "model name" | uniq`) is `Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-6500T CPU @ 2.50GHz` and `grep -E "svm|vmx" /proc/cpuinfo | wc -l` returns 4.

As suggested by [Melebius](https://askubuntu.com/users/250300/melebius), here the full output after running `sudo dpkg-reconfigure virtualbox-dkms`:

```
-------- Uninstall Beginning --------
Module:  virtualbox
Version: 5.2.10
Kernel:  4.15.0-30-generic (x86_64)
-------------------------------------

Status: Before uninstall, this module version was ACTIVE on this kernel.

vboxdrv.ko:
 - Uninstallation
   - Deleting from: /lib/modules/4.15.0-30-generic/updates/dkms/
 - Original module
   - No original module was found for this module on this kernel.
   - Use the dkms install command to reinstall any previous module version.


vboxnetadp.ko:
 - Uninstallation
   - Deleting from: /lib/modules/4.15.0-30-generic/updates/dkms/
 - Original module
   - No original module was found for this module on this kernel.
   - Use the dkms install command to reinstall any previous module version.


vboxnetflt.ko:
 - Uninstallation
   - Deleting from: /lib/modules/4.15.0-30-generic/updates/dkms/
 - Original module
   - No original module was found for this module on this kernel.
   - Use the dkms install command to reinstall any previous module version.


vboxpci.ko:
 - Uninstallation
   - Deleting from: /lib/modules/4.15.0-30-generic/updates/dkms/
 - Original module
   - No original module was found for this module on this kernel.
   - Use the dkms install command to reinstall any previous module version.

depmod...

DKMS: uninstall completed.

-------- Uninstall Beginning --------
Module:  virtualbox
Version: 5.2.10
Kernel:  4.15.0-33-generic (x86_64)
-------------------------------------

Status: Before uninstall, this module version was ACTIVE on this kernel.

vboxdrv.ko:
 - Uninstallation
   - Deleting from: /lib/modules/4.15.0-33-generic/
rmdir: failed to remove '': No such file or directory
 - Original module
   - No original module was found for this module on this kernel.
   - Use the dkms install command to reinstall any previous module version.


vboxnetadp.ko:
 - Uninstallation
   - Deleting from: /lib/modules/4.15.0-33-generic/
rmdir: failed to remove '': No such file or directory
 - Original module
   - No original module was found for this module on this kernel.
   - Use the dkms install command to reinstall any previous module version.


vboxnetflt.ko:
 - Uninstallation
   - Deleting from: /lib/modules/4.15.0-33-generic/
rmdir: failed to remove '': No such file or directory
 - Original module
   - No original module was found for this module on this kernel.
   - Use the dkms install command to reinstall any previous module version.


vboxpci.ko:
 - Uninstallation
   - Deleting from: /lib/modules/4.15.0-33-generic/
rmdir: failed to remove '': No such file or directory
 - Original module
   - No original module was found for this module on this kernel.
   - Use the dkms install command to reinstall any previous module version.

depmod...

DKMS: uninstall completed.

------------------------------
Deleting module version: 5.2.10
completely from the DKMS tree.
------------------------------
Done.
Loading new virtualbox-5.2.10 DKMS files...
Building for 4.15.0-30-generic 4.15.0-33-generic
Building initial module for 4.15.0-30-generic
Done.

vboxdrv:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/4.15.0-30-generic/updates/dkms/

vboxnetadp.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/4.15.0-30-generic/updates/dkms/

vboxnetflt.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/4.15.0-30-generic/updates/dkms/

vboxpci.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/4.15.0-30-generic/updates/dkms/

depmod...

DKMS: install completed.
Building initial module for 4.15.0-33-generic
Done.

vboxdrv:
Running module version sanity check.
modinfo: ERROR: could not get modinfo from 'vboxdrv': Invalid argument
 - Original module
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/4.15.0-33-generic/updates/dkms/

vboxnetadp.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
modinfo: ERROR: could not get modinfo from 'vboxnetadp': Invalid argument
 - Original module
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/4.15.0-33-generic/updates/dkms/

vboxnetflt.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
modinfo: ERROR: could not get modinfo from 'vboxnetflt': Invalid argument
 - Original module
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/4.15.0-33-generic/updates/dkms/

vboxpci.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
modinfo: ERROR: could not get modinfo from 'vboxpci': Invalid argument
 - Original module
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/4.15.0-33-generic/updates/dkms/

depmod...

DKMS: install completed.
Job for virtualbox.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status virtualbox.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript virtualbox, action "restart" failed.
● virtualbox.service - LSB: VirtualBox Linux kernel module
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/virtualbox; generated)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2018-08-27 15:38:36 UTC; 5ms ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 9229 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/virtualbox start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Aug 27 15:38:36 cmsuite-build-machine systemd[1]: Starting LSB: VirtualBox Linux kernel module...
Aug 27 15:38:36 cmsuite-build-machine virtualbox[9229]:  * Loading VirtualBox kernel modules...
Aug 27 15:38:36 cmsuite-build-machine virtualbox[9229]:  * modprobe vboxdrv failed. Please use 'dmesg' to find out why
Aug 27 15:38:36 cmsuite-build-machine virtualbox[9229]:    ...fail!
Aug 27 15:38:36 cmsuite-build-machine systemd[1]: virtualbox.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Aug 27 15:38:36 cmsuite-build-machine systemd[1]: virtualbox.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 27 15:38:36 cmsuite-build-machine systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: VirtualBox Linux kernel module.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: As far as I understood I need the `[arch=amd64]` in order to avoid the error message `N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'contrib/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian bionic InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)

Comment: Thanks for the related post, but this means the official instructions made by Oracle are not working!

Comment: You could get [`virtualbox-5.2`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/virtualbox) using the default Ubuntu repository. I wouldn’t bother with 3rd party repositories unless there is an important improvement in the  version provided by them.

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue on clean 18.04 LTS. It seems you have not enabled all official Ubuntu repositories. Try `sudo add-apt-repository main`, `sudo add-apt-repository universe`, `sudo add-apt-repository multiverse`, `sudo apt-get update`, `sudo apt-get install -f`. In other words it is your fault, not Oracle'.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa)

Comment: Thanks for your answers. However, when I do what @N0rbert described, I got the error which is described [in this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/958110/failed-to-start-lsb-virtualbox-linux-kernel-module/958156), which tells me not to use the official version

Comment: Did you forget to enable CPU virtualization in BIOS? Are you sure that your CPU supports it? Please add output of `cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep "model name" | uniq` and `grep -E "svm|vmx" /proc/cpuinfo | wc -l` to the question.

Comment: About DKMS errors see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/41120/66509). You need to install `dkms` package.

Comment: I updated the question.

Comment: `DKMS` is installed and up-to-date. And still: When I am following the default instructions, this should not be needed, right?

Comment: Please run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure virtualbox-dkms` and add the _full_ output into your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was facing the same issue. I suggest you disable [TPM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trusted_Platform_Module) and SecureBoot in your UEFI settings.