# How to keep Virtualbox working on Ubuntu 20.04 after kernel update?

Tags: 20.04, kernel, virtualbox

So, after the recent kernel update to kernel 5.8, my Virtualbox installation broke. It couldn't run any VMs and gave me an error message when I tried. When that happened, I didn't know about this site (I was, and still am, a GNU/Linux novice), and so didn't ask a question about this here. I didn't know what to do even after researching on the internet, so I went and reversed the update (I currently use 5.7.17-generic). So, my question is:

How can I keep Virtualbox working after a kernel update? Or, if that is not possible, what steps can I take after a kernel update to get it to work again?

**Note**: When answering, please keep in mind that I have the version of Virtualbox from the Ubuntu 20.04 repos installed and that I would like to be able to keep Virtualbox working after a kernel update without a reinstall (but I am willing to if I must).

If you need anything, just ask.

Thanking you in advance.

Comment: My understanding is that you need to grab the newest .deb and install that. The download location starts [here](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads). I personally haven't had to do so, so I can't vouch for the validity - but it was the solution to several other recent questions about this.

Answer (score 0):

Virtualbox is compiled against a certain kernel (range). So if the kernel changes VB might break.

Either you get a new VB that fits for your kernel or try to get a dkms version.

See [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/203586/how-do-i-install-the-virtualbox-dkms-package) for more infos on a VB-DKMS